# Where i lost my URL in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express, subdomain

I was trying to build  an  app with different subdomains . I can fetch each subdomain by `subdomain` module and can access like /subdomain/user . I'm getting two different url in my modules even it shares same callback handle for listening the server

Lets look at code briefly

**main.js**

```
var subdomain=require('subdomain')({ base: 'example.loc' });
var express=require('express')
var user=require('./app/user');

express()
.use(subdomain)
.use(function  (req,res,next) {
    console.log('This is from main');
    console.log(req.url);
    next();
})
.use('/subdomain/user',user)
.listen(8808)
```

**user.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var routes=require('./routes');
    app
    .use(routes);

module.exports=app
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();

router.use(function  (req,res,next) {
    console.log('This from user');
    console.log(req.url);
    next();
})
router.get('/subdomain/user',function(req,res,next){
 res.send('This is from user');
});
module.exports = router;
```

If i call the url , `user.example.loc` im getting log as follows

```
This is  from  main
/subdomain/user
This is from  user
/
```

Question is , where i lost the url i assigned using subdomain module .
I checked the subdomain module source , i could not find any reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An express `app` is actually a `Router` and `Router.use()` strips the mount path from the url before processing it.

From the [`Router` docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router):

> Every express application has a builtin `app` router.

And from the [`Router.use()` docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.use):

> The "mount" path is stripped and is not visible to the middleware
>   function. The main effect of this feature is that mounted middleware
>   may operate without code changes regardless of its "prefix" pathname.

So, you're function here:

```
router.get('/subdomain/user',function(req,res,next){
    res.send('This is from user');
});
```

isn't getting called because the `router` it is a part of is mounted to `/subdomain/user` and the gets stripped away (as you've seen). If you change it's path to `/` it should work:

```
router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    res.send('This is from user');
});
```

Comment: Thank you , i got my URL :)